# Telethon client doesnt run the second time

Tags: python, telethon

Im experimenting with my codes. I have written a very simple code which automatically replies to channel posts. It's all fine and works. Now I wanted to chain 2 of my codes using sys.exit(os.system())

The 2 codes run fine, after the 2nd code, it should start at the first code again, but if the first code tries to run for the 2nd time then I get an error about the client. Ive also tried other methods: exit() quit() and so on but everytime I get the same error.

This is my first code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon import functions, types
from time import sleep
from telethon import functions, types, errors, connection, TelegramClient, events
import asyncio
import os
import sys

api_id = 123456789
api_hash = 'API_HASH'
CHANNEL = [-100123456789]

client1 = TelegramClient(session1, api_id, api_hash)

print("Starting Client 1...")
@client1.on(events.NewMessage(CHANNEL))
async def main(event):
    
    if -100123456789 == event.chat_id:
        await client1.send_message(event.chat_id, 'my message', comment_to=event.id)
        print("Message sent. Exiting and running script2")
        sys.exit(os.system("python script2.py"))

client1.start()
client1.run_until_disconnected()
```

This is my second code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon import functions, types
from time import sleep
from telethon import functions, types, errors, connection, TelegramClient, events
import asyncio
import os
import sys

api_id = 123456789
api_hash = 'API_HASH'
CHANNEL = [-100123456789]

client2 = TelegramClient(session2, api_id, api_hash)

print("Starting Client 2...")
@client2.on(events.NewMessage(CHANNEL))
async def main(event):
      
    if -100123456789 == event.chat_id:
        await client2.send_message(event.chat_id, 'my message', comment_to=event.id)
        print("Message sent Exiting and running script1.")
        sys.exit(os.system("python script1.py"))

client2.start()
client2.run_until_disconnected()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Starting Client 1...
Message sent. Exiting and running script2
Starting Client 2...
Message sent. Exiting and running script1
Starting Client 1...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\script1.py", line 26, in <module>
    client1.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 134, in start
    else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 141, in _start
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 540, in connect
    self.session.auth_key = self._sender.auth_key
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\sessions\sqlite.py", line 180, in auth_key
    self._update_session_table()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\sessions\sqlite.py", line 194, in _update_session_table
    c.execute('delete from sessions')
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<Connection._send_loop() running at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:311> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<Connection._recv_loop() running at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:329> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-4' coro=<MTProtoSender._send_loop() running at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:462> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<MTProtoSender._recv_loop() running at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:505> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
```

What am I doing wrong? I am grateful for every help I can get. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remember that `os.system` does not return until the called process exits.  Thus, you are nesting an infinite layer of processes here, each waiting for the next to exit.  You can consider using `os.execv` instead, but it would be smarter to combine these into one script that changes its actions based on the state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ive tried it out now but I couldnt figure it out. How exactly do I need to use it so it works? I tried using os.execv() but I got error that execv expected 2 arguments, got only 1 I dont even know which kind of arguments it needs. Or is there another way instead of having both scripts in one script?

Comment: Did you think to check the documentation?  Python has EXCELLENT documentation.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html  `os.execlp( 'python', 'script1.py' )`.  However, running them as one process would be smarter.  You can have the functions in separate files and `import` them into your main, if you want.